# Minimal spectrum of graded rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, tensor-products, graded-rings

Let $R$ be a left Noetherian ($\mathbb N$-)graded ring and let $R_0$ be its $0$-th component. When $R$ is commutative it is well-known, and easy to prove, that the minimal prime ideals of $R$ are necessarily graded (see for example [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/176068/are-minimal-prime-ideals-in-a-graded-ring-graded)). What about the non-commutative case? Is it still true that minimal prime ideals are graded?

A similar question is the following. In the above situation, suppose that $R$ is flat as an $R_0$-module, are all the minimal prime ideals of $R$ of the form $R\otimes_{R_0}\frak p$ for some minimal prime ideal $\frak p$ of $R_0$.

If this is not true, is there any standard hypothesis to make it true?